# “Gradle files have changed since last project sync.” message always shows up after change laptop's timezone

Tags: android, gradle

Everything works OK until I change my laptop's timezone from UTC -8:00 to UTC +7:00. After that, “Gradle files have changed since last project sync...” message always shows up.

How can I fix it? Of course I don't want to change my timezone to UTC -8:00 again.

Comment: What is the particular problem with just doing the Gradle sync? How frequently are  you changing your time zone?

Comment: @CommonsWare: After I sync project, this gradle message shows up again. I've already re-install Window, so I need to change timezone. I don't do it usually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, that's strange.

Here is what I would do:

1. Close the project in Android Studio (so you are back at the Welcome dialog), then close Android Studio altogether
2. Back up the project, so that if the following steps go crazy, I can recover
3. Delete the `build/`, `.gradle/`, and `.idea/` directories from the project root, along with the `*.iml` file in the project root
4. Delete the `build/` directory and the `*.iml` file from each module in the project (e.g., `app/`)
5. Open Android Studio and import the cleaned-up project

This will force a complete regeneration of the `.idea/` directory and `*.iml` files, which are the primary "project files" that the Gradle sync operation is supposed to sync.

Or, just wait 24 hours, as the problem may go away on its own.

Comment: ..or just scream big F word and delete whole thing, then re-git clone entire project from repo like I did